# Problems importing python-pcre (pcre might not be installed correctly)

Tags: python, pcre

I have installed pcre with homebrew. However this does not seem to work with this package: [python-pcre](https://github.com/awahlig/python-pcre) as it seems like it is missing `jit´.

I tried installing pcre on my own however the guides i could find did not work on macOS Sierra. Does any one have any tips on how i can get this packeage to work on macOS Sierra?

`import pcre
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/srf-3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pcre.py", line 29, in <module>
    import _pcre
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/srf-3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pcre.cpython-35m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _pcre_assign_jit_stack
  Referenced from: /usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/srf-3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pcre.cpython-35m-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/srf-3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pcre.cpython-35m-darwin.so`

Comment: FYI, there is a great PyPi `regex` module that accepts a lot of PCRE compatible patterns.

Comment: Yes, thank you! :) I figured this out eventually. However if anyone solves this I'll up vote and accept the answer. Might help someone else.